# Get values from parent array passed to CodeIgniter3 Template parser during the Loop

Tags: php, codeigniter, loops, parsing, codeigniter-3

I have this in my Controller:

```
$data['baseurl'] = $baseurl;
$data['popularServers'] = $serverdata; // $serverdata is an Array with info got from database
```

Now in my View i do this:

```
{popularServers}
            <a href="{baseurl}/server/id/{id}" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start">
           <div class="float-left">
           <span class="serverlogo" style="background-image: url('{logo_url}')"></span>
                                </div>
           <div class="float-right">
           <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
           <h5 class="mb-1">{name}</h5> <input type="hidden" class="rating" value="{ranking}" data-readonly/>
           </div>
           <p class="mb-1">{short_description}</p>
           <span class="badge badge-success">Minecraft</span>
            <span class="badge badge-secondary">#bedwars</span>
            <span class="badge badge-secondary">#realms</span>
            </div>
            </a>
{/popularServers}
```

My problem is that the {baseurl} isn't availabile during the Loop. Is there any alternative solution?

Note that:

- I want to not use the `<?php echo base_url(); ?>` because I want to
  keep the views as clean as possible from PHP code.
- I can't merge the two arrays, because the {baseurl} is like a
  "global" parsing variable in a "global" array as I specified it in
  MY_Parser.php whereas the {popular_servers} subArray is in a
  particular controller.

Comment: Should you use `$data['baseurl'] = $this->baseurl;` instead? Or `$data['baseurl'] = base_url();`?

Comment: $baseurl is a function based on base_url();

It's defined in MY_Parser.php as this:
`$baseurl = substr(base_url(), 0, -1);`

Comment: how about `$data['baseurl_custom'] = $baseurl;` ?